# drupal is working very slow on my windows xp localhost

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, content-management-system, wampserver

I installed drupal on my machine which is running WAMPserver latest one with PHP 5.3.54, but after installation it is running very slow.

Is there any tweaks which need to be done to make it fast??

I tried joomla and it is working very fast, I dont know what is wrong with Drupal.

Please let me know if there is any solution.

My drupal version is 6.x-1.2 and I am using drupal-commons from acquia

Thanks
Pranay

Comment: Just a general thought: do you have any sort of debug enabled / caching disabled?

Comment: Joomla 6.x-1.2? What the hell is that? Drupal versioning applied to a competitive CMS?

Comment: Do you run Drupal with many extra modules enabled? Any particular thirdparty modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen similar issues with Drupal under some Windows AMP packages. Installing a [PHP accelerator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_PHP_Cache), like [eAccelerator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAccelerator) or [APC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_PHP_Cache#Alternative_PHP_Cache) made a **huge** speed improvement.

Or you can switch to an [_AMP package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs) that includes a PHP accelerator. [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) comes with eAccelerator pre-configured and works really well with Drupal, in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried increasing your

```
realpath_cache_size
```

in your php.ini file? Try setting it as 2M and see what happens.

Comment: I found that solution I tried it is improves but still it is slow as compare to joomla, is this a problem in drupal?? or I need to do some more tweaking in wamp???